# Formatting an SD card for Panda Board ES

Tags: electronics, operating-systems

I have a Panda Board ES. I am not able to get it to boot. I sent it back to SVTronics to get it checked and they said that the board is OK; I am the one who is not able to configure it properly.

After doing a little research and following all the directions on the Panda Board and Ubuntu website, I am still not able to get the board to boot. I think the problem is how I am formatting the SD card. I am using disk utility for Mac to format the SD card to "MSDOS(FAT)" partition.

I would like to know how to format an "SD Card" on a Macintosh to install Ubuntu on it for Panda Board ES.

Comment: This is not the correct place to ask this question - as it does not pertain to the Raspberry Pi. May I suggest you check the support site and/or forums for the Panda Board

Comment: I have already done that ... its kind of a dead community there .. that is why I asked this question here, thinking that someone might be able to remedy the situation

Comment: There is a new stackexchange site [robotics.SE]. They might be able to help.

Comment: @Manishearth Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your problem is not the filesystem format (although you should probably using Linux EXT2/EXT3/EXT4 instead of MS-DOS/FAT).  Is the bootloader installed properly?

Here are some posts on putting an Ubuntu bootloader on an SD card:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/191902/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-my-sd-card
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=760477

More broadly, have you looked at this wiki, dedicated to putting Ubuntu on Panda boards?
http://www.omappedia.org/wiki/OMAP_Ubuntu_Main

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. I was able to resolve the issue. I was not using the dd command properly. Also FAT partition on SD card is ok for running linux.